# What is the identity for Tuples?

Tags: tuples

My question is, what list *p* in the following statement returns the list *q*?

```
Tuples[{{p},{q}}]
```

If we think of Tuples as a binary operator then *p* would be the identity for Tuples.

I thought an empty list would work, but evaluating the following

```
Tuples[{{},{1,2,3}}]
```

gives {} instead of {1,2,3} or {{1},{2},{3}} as I had hoped.

The following doesn't work either:

```
Tuples[{{\[EmptySet]},{1,2,3}}]
```

Certainly, I could write a function like the following

```
altTuples[p_List,q_List]:= If[Length[p]==0,q,Tuples[{p,q}]
```

That does exactly what I want, but I want to know if I'm missing something. Is there in fact an identity for Tuples? Is there a way to do what I want with Outer? I've tried the obvious solutions with no luck.

Comment: How do you want your `altTuples[]` to behave when the length of $p$ is not zero?  For example `altTuples[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}]` returns `Tuples[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}]`, probably not what you want.

Comment: I corrected altTuples. Actually I want it to return Tuples[{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}}].

I think Nothing is what I was looking for.

Comment: What you have above is *almost* correct (up to a typo).  Anyway seems to produce what you want.  'AltTuples[{p,q}]` gives the same output as Tuples[p,q] when the first argument is a list with non-zero length.

Answer (score 7):

If `{{1},{2},{3}}` is fine, you can use [`Nothing`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html):

```
Tuples[{Nothing, {1, 2, 3}}]
(* {{1}, {2}, {3}} *)
```

If you want `{1,2,3}`, you can `Flatten` the result, of course.

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Inactive[Sequence][]` as identity like this:

```
Tuples[{{Inactive[Sequence][]},{q}}]//Activate
```

> {{q}}

Answer (score 4):

Use [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) to define a function that behaves as desired:

```
ClearAll[iDentity]
iDentity /: {iDentity[___], a : {__}} := iDentity[a]
iDentity /: Tuples[iDentity[a_]] := a

Tuples[{iDentity[], {q}}]
```

> {q}

```
Tuples[{iDentity[blah], {1, 2, 3}}]
```

> {1, 2, 3}

Alternatively, define your function `altTuples` with two signatures:

```
ClearAll[altTuples]
altTuples[{tuplesIdentity | {} | Nothing, a_List}] := a
altTuples[x_] := Tuples[x]

altTuples[{{x, y}, {1, 2}}]
```

> {{x, 1}, {x, 2}, {y, 1}, {y, 2}}

```
altTuples[{tuplesIdentity, {1, 2}}]
```

> {1, 2}

```
altTuples[{{}, {1, 2}}]
```

> {1, 2}

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
altTuples[p_List, q_List] := If[Length[p] == 0, q, Tuples[{p, q}]]
```

The statement

```
altTuples[{}, {d, e, f}]
```

returns

```
{d, e, f}
```

and

```
altTuples[{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}]
```

returns

```
{{a, d}, {a, e}, {a, f}, {b, d}, {b, e}, {b, f}, {c, d}, {c, e}, {c, f}}
```